# Which android data technique to use for my app?

Tags: php, android, sqlite

I am new to android and I have some questions related to the data storage technique for my app. I am creating an app (like splitwise) where multiple users can insert and update their data and can see others data as well.
I read about the techniques that android provides like :

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- SQLite Databases
- Network Connection

After researching I came to a conclusion that I have to create a database on web server and use php scripts to access that data.

Questions :
 - Is this the only way to save data on-line using web server and php
   scripts ?
 - Do I need to create local database using SqlLite also to store data
   when the app is running to avoid multiple calls to web ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be searching for REST API. Please take a look @ [Andoid-PHP Samples/ tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will research about REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services like **Firebase** or Google's **Clouds Endpoints** to simplify the creation of your backend

Comment: Thanks I will read about it.